# Kotlin multiplatform mobile - fail to run iOS project - missing one or more architectures required by this target

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, mobile, kotlin-multiplatform

I create KMM(Kotlin multiplatform mobile) project using Android studio 4.1 RC3 and try to run the iOS App (with default code) but stuck with following error:

> error : The linked and embedded framework 'shared.framework' is
> missing one or more architectures required by this target: arm64. (in
> target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')

But when I just hit 'build', it get built successfully. Only happening only when hit 'run' from Android studio. Mean while I used Xcode to run the same project and face no issues getting it deployed into the simulator successfully.

By the way I was following this official KMM guide
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/create-first-app.html

Using Xcode 14 ( I tried simulators with iOS14,13.5,12.1) using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6

Answer (score 5):

This problem is most probably caused by Xcode 12 adding new simulator architectures. As a workaround, one can try adding `arm64` to the `Disable Architectures` list in `Build Settings`. See the related issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-41854)

Comment: I've added arm64 to excluded architectures build setting using xcode. now iPhone simulator boots up but app not getting installed on it. Look like a known issue.

Comment: Same issue as @Niroshan. My workaround for now is running the app from AS and then run it from XCode that will be updated from the previous execution